# I am getting NullReferenceException when devices orientation change in xamarin.forms in Android 9

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my android app that developed using Xamarin.forms, whenever I changed the device's orientation I am getting a NullReferenceException and app getting crashed in Android 9. But in previous android version's app is working very well. There is no crash.

This is MainActivity.cs

```
namespace RSMapp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "FIRE", Icon = "@drawable/launcherIcon", Theme = "@style/splashscreen", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

        protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            TryToGetPermissions();

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
            base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
            UserDialogs.Init(this);
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Instance = this;
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Plugin.InputKit.Platforms.Droid.Config.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            UltimateXFSettup.Initialize(this);
            LoadApplication(new App());

        }


}

}
```

I tried deleting  **ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait** , but problem exist.

After changing the orientation portrait to landscape getting this in Output window

```
10-18 11:52:37.366 I/MultiWindowDecorSupport(19021): updateCaptionType >> DecorView@3acb272[MainActivity], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
10-18 11:52:37.366 D/MultiWindowDecorSupport(19021): setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@3acb272[MainActivity]
10-18 11:52:37.373 D/ViewRootImpl@403bf69[MainActivity](19021): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=[0,0][2048,1536] ci=[0,48][0,0] vi=[0,48][0,0] or=2
10-18 11:52:37.399 D/ViewRootImpl@403bf69[MainActivity](19021): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][2048,1536] new=[0,0][2048,1536] result=0x23 surface={true 490213163008} changed=false
10-18 11:52:37.401 D/OpenGLRenderer(19021): eglDestroySurface = 0x7222da2700, 0x7222fb4000
10-18 11:52:37.402 D/OpenGLRenderer(19021): eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7222da2700, 0x7222fb4010
Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**Problem exist in this code.**

```
public override Resources Resources
{
    get
    {
        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 25)
        {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.SetToDefaults();
            Context context = CreateConfigurationContext(config);
            Resources resources = context.Resources;
            return resources;
        }
        else
        {
            Resources res = base.Resources;
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.SetToDefaults();
            res.UpdateConfiguration(config, res.DisplayMetrics);
            return res;
        }

    }
}
```

I am using this to omit user's system level font size changing to the app. This gives the error in Android 9

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

delete `ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait`

then add this in your `MainActivity` :

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Comment: not working. if I put the phone to auto rotation and change the orientation, app getting crash.

Comment: @D.madushanka you make a breakpoint in Mainactivity's onCreate method,see if it break when you change the orientation

Comment: @D.madushanka but still crash ?if it go into the OnConfigurationChanged method ?

Comment: it hit in the OnConfigurationChanged method, I think I found the problem. I will update.

Comment: @D.madushanka it's really strange,could you share a test project ?i will test it on my side.

Comment: @D.madushanka if you dont use  the above codes (Resource),if it crash ?

Comment: I actually need those, I don't know why it crash in Android 9.

Comment: @D.madushanka maybe you could share a simple project